# Can we get something on the ask question page to discourage grammar questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The absolute number one close reason we have right now on Writers is that the question is an English grammar question which belongs on English.SE.  I know we won't have migration paths until we are a full site, but can we now, in the beta layout, get something (whether in the title box or the How to Format box) that discourages grammar questions?  Or do we have to wait for that until we've graduated?

Comment: This should also be added to the "What questions should I *not* ask here" section of the FAQ page.

Comment: Is it really such an issue closing them? How many do we have?

Comment: @John - it's not a huge issue, but appears to be becoming an issue a la the "recipe request" of SeasonedAdvice - and a bad intro for new users to the site.  I'd prefer they're warned in advance, you know?

Comment: @sjohn it was already there, and has been for at least 2 weeks, which tells you just how often that gets read.

Comment: @Jeff - Silly me, I checked the FAQ page before posting that comment...but it was the *meta* FAQ page.

Answer (score 5):

Well the [faq](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq) already contains this advice:

> and [your question] is *not* about …
>
> - The strictly interpreted correctness of English grammar or syntax rules
>
> … it is welcome here!

But, I can certainly improve the how to ask. Here's what I just changed it to:

> #### How to Ask
>
> **Is your question about writing, copywriting, publishing or editing?**
>
> If your question is about the strictly interpreted correctness of English grammar or syntax rules, please [ask on English](http://english.stackexchange.com), not here.
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com)** instead.
>
> [read the faq »](/faq)

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for - a nice, gentle reminder!